# Oracle OCCI - get column by name instead of index

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

Using oracle OCCI is it possible instead of supplying an index for the column when requesting data from a query resultset, to actually pass the column name and get the data?

So instead of doing: (pseudocode)

```
std::string query = "SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMERS;";

std::string myresult = oracle.getString(1); // name column in query
```

you'd do this:

```
std::string myresult = oracle.getString("NAME"); //column name to get string from
```

is there any way to do this?  I have looked around, but been unable to find anything, besides perhaps going to fetch the table's metadata.

Comment: getVector() could be explored more.

Comment: @DumbCoder: have you used it before? Can you give an example of usage? Not much to be found on the net in examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just read the [*documentation*](http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/support/oracle/doc/10.2/nav/portal_5.htm).

It says `ResultSet` has a method `getColumnListMetaData()`, which produces a `vector` of `MetaData`.

Most probably you can then use `MetaData::getString` to find the name of column.

And if so then you can use a `std::map<string, int>` to map the column names back to indices.

And with that *name* → *index* mapping in place you can then implement a `getString` that takes a query result and column name as arguments.

Possibly someone who has used this particular database can help you better, but it seems that all that was needed was to take a look at the documentation.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: this sounds like a plan, only I need the data prior to the query, and the index is the index of the column inside the query, not the index of that column in the table.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but you can get the MetaData from a ResultSet where the index would correctly match your projected columns.